# Get list of all Activities available on the System

Tags: android, android-activity

Since the system should know about the available Activities as they are declared in the appropriate `AndroidManifest.xml` files which are evaluated during installation:
Is there a way to query these Activities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, have a look at `PackageManager.getInstalledPackages` method. Here is the example of printing registered activities names:

```
List<PackageInfo> pInfos = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
for (PackageInfo pInfo : pInfos) {
  ActivityInfo[] aInfos = pInfo.activities;
  if (aInfos != null) {
    for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : aInfos) {
      Log.i("ACT", activityInfo.name);
      // do whatever else you like... 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    String description = (String) p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(pm);
    String  label= p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    String packageName = p.packageName;
    String versionName = p.versionName;
    String versionCode = p.versionCode;
    String icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
//Continue to extract other info about the app...
}
```

Note: Add this permission to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Add this to above code:

```
PackageManager.getactivities -- I have not used this PackageManager.getactivities but I hope it will work for you....
```

Comment: `pm.getInstalledPackages(0)` - this will not work since you need to specify what kind of info PackageManager should return (i.e. PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES). Check my answer below. Btw, `android.permission.GET_TASKS` is not needed to enumerate activities I was able to deal without it.

Comment: I have mentioned PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES to be added as the above code I have used to fetch the list of installed apps in the device...

Comment: You do not need `getApplicationContext()` -- just call `getPackageManager()` on `ctx`.